# How to do load test based on User ID using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance, load-testing

My app having six modules for each modules having separate URLs:

1)`http://church/wpApp/api.php?mod=gallery&method=get Videos&format=json` -- with this  URL, I can be done the load test Using  JMeter.

My another Sub- category Url having ID-based URL. Here it is possible to apply load test Why because this URL having id this ID  based Test only for particular ID.

2) `http://felda/wpApp/api.php?mod=posts&method=ratetopost&post_id=510&comment_author_email=t_content=hello&user_id=28`.  ( "ID=28")--

It is possible to do  LOAD  test "ID "Based URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it can be done, just add a HTTP Request sampler and configure it like:

[image: JMeter HTTP User ID]

Where this `user_id` parameter can be:

- something static, i.e. `28`
- something data-driven, i.e. JMeter Variable originating from [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG) like `${userid}`
- something random i.e. between 1 and 100 using [__Random() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) like `${__Random(1,100)}`

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. In your URL add a random function. This will pick a random Id in each iteration and use it in URL.

http://felda/wpApp/api.php?mod=posts&method=ratetopost&post_id=510&comment_author_email=t_content=hello&user_id=`${__Random(10000, 99999, id)}`

2. Similarly you can use [counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) method.